# Escape \ without escaping group in regex

Tags: php, regex

Mondays, however, how do I get a regex that will replace all `\` that do not have a `"` after?

I have tried:

```
$toBeCleaned = preg_replace('/\\(?!")/',"\\\\",$toBeCleaned);
```

Which of course says:

```
preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 5
```

Thing is I can get this to work on: http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php just fine.

However I modified it to:

```
$toBeCleaned = preg_replace('/\\\(?!")/',"\\\\",$toBeCleaned);
```

Which does not error out but at the same time, of course due to the escaping done, does not work.

I can't seem to comprehend on a Monday morning why I can't get it to do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running @hank's regex by actually using a word to replace the text I found out my regex was working pefectly fine it just wasn't replacing correctly. So I changed it to:

```
$toBeCleaned = preg_replace('/\\\(?!")/',"\\\\\\",$toBeCleaned);
```

Which does actually work.

I am accepting this answer too because of the problems that can occur from using negated character classes as mentioned on this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

I do hate Mondays.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a expression that will replace all backslashes that does not have a " after.

```
$toBeCleaned = preg_replace('/\\\[^"]/', 'SLASH', $toBeCleaned);
```

The question however, what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a better way, regular expressions in not always the answer.

Comment: Thanks this helped to find the problem with my regex, although this page does state a problem with negative character classes so I have decided to keep with my regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html